WinmergeU.exe mangles non-ASCII characters
I have a file with this text (on Windows 10):
'content' => '<h3>This is Schüler Doc1</h3>
  <p>glurk</p>
  <p>Straße</p>
  <p>Europäisch</p>
   <p>München</p>',

The file is definitely in utf-8, per the "file" command. The text is shown correctly in both Notepad++ and PhpStorm. In WinMergeU (64-bit, latest version) , however, the text appears like this:
'content' => '<h3>This is SchÃ¼ler Doc1</h3>
    <p>glurk</p>
    <p>StraÃŸe</p>
    <p>EuropÃ¤isch</p>
    <p>MÃ¼nchen</p>', 

WinMergeU shows the file encoding as 1252. I haven't found any way to change that, since WinMerge only accepts decimal encodings and won't accept utf-8 as an option.

Windows assigns codepage 65001 for UTF8; try that. (Not programming or development.)

For others: For code files, you can add a comment at the beginning with a non-ascii character. // ü make WinMerge treat it as utf-8
If all your files are utf-8, you can go to Edit -> Options -> Codepage in WinMerge, and set a Custom Codepage to 65001.
